# overloading rated current capability of a connector

Tags: power, current, heat, power-dissipation

If each connetion of a screw terminal (the one in question in the picture) is rated for 3A at 380V, is it probably safe to use each one for 12A at 12V? Is there a way to work this out? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... is rated for 3A at 380V,

3 A is the current the terminals can carry. There will be some resistance in the terminals and they will heat up due to the power dissipated in each terminal. *P = I<sup>2</sup>R*. Note that the heating has nothing to do with the voltage between adjacent terminals or a terminal and earth.

380 V is the insulation rating. That is the maximum allowable voltage difference between any two terminals or a terminal and the fastening screw (see the mounting holes between terminals). This has nothing to do with the current rating of the terminals.

> ... is it probably safe to use each one for 12A at 12V? Is there a way to work this out?

No. Each terminal knows nothing about what voltage it is at relative to anything else. All it knows is the current running through it.

None of the wiring shown in your photograph looks like it is rated for 3 A.

Answer (score 1):

There **is** an easy way to work this out.

If the manufacturer's datasheet says that the maximum current is 3A then you can not safely use the connector for any current greater than 3A.

The voltage and current ratings for these connectors are independent. You must satisfy both of them.